How does the flask server distinguishes that connection is from existing client or new client?
I am trying to understand how server like flask is able to distinguishes if the request is through the new connection or existing connection.
Today I have seen a website that does not allow access to its api (accessing through fetch api in javascript) until and unless it is already authenticated in the login page. I am wondering how this is happening behind the scene at tcp level.
I have created a very simple http server in python. So Whenever, I connect with this server, I get 'Hello, World!' response.
Now I want to modify the below in such a way that If I use fetch API of javascript then it should reply me "you have already connected" as I am using fetch from the tab where I have already got the "Hello World!" response, that emulates I am already authenticated.
import socket
 
def handle_request(client_socket):
    request_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not request_data:
        return
 
    # Assuming the request is a simple HTTP GET request
    response = b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\nHello, World!"
    client_socket.sendall(response)
    client_socket.close()
 
def run_server(host, port):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:
        server_socket.bind((host, port))
        server_socket.listen(5)
        print(f"Server listening on {host}:{port}")
 
        while True:
            client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
            print(f"Connected to {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}")
            handle_request(client_socket)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server("localhost", 8080)


from what I understand you want to authenticate a user and check if the user is authenticated right? Since you're using flask, flask login is probably what you want. Simply use if (current_user.is_authenticated):         return redirect(url_for("home")) after that at the start of the route handling function
